# Organizing URI segments in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
function orders(){

        $order_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if($order_id){
            $data['main_content'] = "admin-order-page";
            $data['order_id'] = $order_id;
            $this->load->view("includes/cp-template",$data);
        }else{
            $data['main_content'] = "admin-orders";
            $this->load->view("includes/cp-template",$data);
        }



    }
```

Above is my orders method in my controller, so www.myexample.com/orders

I'm wondering what is the proper way of handling information passed in the url. In my example, you have just /orders going to a particular view, and if a id is appended, /orders/23, it will go to a product page.

I now want to add pagination on my /orders view, and will want to pass the page number in the url, like /orders/page/2. Should I just add some more logic looking for the uri of "page"?

Is there a better way of organizing all of this?

Comment: You could use CodeIgniter routing to match the pagination URL and make it calls the function that lists the orders with pagination instead of calling the one that gives a specific detail of an order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an url like **www.myexample.com/orders/page/2/4** you can read the arguments as example below:

```
class Orders extends CI_Controller{

    public function __contruct()
    {
        parent::__contruct();
    }

    public function page($page_number, $limit)
    {
        echo 'page number ' . $page_number . ' with limit of ' . $limit;
            //the above line prints:  "page number 2 with limit of 4"
    }
}
```

Remember that the URI patter is builded according to:

```
domain.com/{controller}/{function}/{parameter 1} ... , {parameter N}
```